# Как получить из списка только определенный тип данных?

Tags: python

Я могу получить тип данных `int` из списка `arr` следующим кодом:

```
arr = [1, 'a', 2, 'b']
parsed_arr = []

for value in arr:
    if type(value) == 'int':
        parsed_arr.append(value)
```

Есть ли способ сделать это проще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) - это наиболее идиоматический способ:

```
In [4]: res = [x for x in arr if isinstance(x, int)]

In [5]: res
Out[5]: [1, 2]
```

---

`isinstance()` - может проверять одновременно несколько разных типов:

```
In [6]: [isinstance(x, (int, float)) for x in [1, 3.14, 'pi']]
Out[6]: [True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 'a', 2, 'b']
parsed_arr = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), arr))

print(parsed_arr)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: И всё же код надо пояснять. Код без пояснений не приветствуется на SO )